# Remove the option to log in with ClaimID

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, login, openid

The [login page](https://stackoverflow.com/users/login) offers an option to login with [ClaimID](http://claimid.com), which has ceased operations according to the notice on their site.

[image]

Are there any plans to remove the ClaimID button from the login page in the near future? I guess existing users should still be able to login somehow.

Comment: We still list them likely because none of us use ClaimID so nobody here even noticed that they went down. Thanks for letting us know. :)

Comment: @AnnaLear: I noticed - but used an openid delegation, which was cached long enough. Built this http://claimid-dump.joelpurra.com/ to get my data out though.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Thanks for reporting - I have now removed claimID as an OpenID provider from our codebase.

This will be out in the next build rev 2013.12.13.1227 (meta rev 2013.12.13.1759).