# Cannot associate other communities to my Stack Exchange account

Tags: support, login, user-accounts, stack-exchange-openid

I log in to Stack Exchange using a Stack Exchange account (just Stack Exchange email and password – no Google, Facebook, etc.). So far, so good.

But when I try to login or sign up to another Stack Exchange community using this authentication, there is no option for adding it to my profile. I have only these 3 options for sign up:

1. Google
2. Facebook
3. Completing a form for a new id

When I visit the sites that I'm already associated (like this Meta or English Leaners), everything works well, I'm correctly authenticated.

How can I become a member of other Stack Exchange sites? Am I facing a bug?

Comment: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/307647/support-for-openid-ends-on-july-1-2018

Comment: @PolyGeo Oh, thanks for the info! But maybe I'm talking about a different thing, I'll edit my question to clarify. EDIT: Now I get what the problem is, I just need to login with my email and password and my account will add the new site

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When I created my Stack Exchange account, I used Stack Exchange OpenID for it, but as PolyGeo pointed out in a comment, support for OpenID was dropped. Now it became a normal Stack Exchange account.

To add an account to a new Stack Exchange site, all you need to do is log in to the new site using your email and password. This will present a new window asking if you want to create an account in this new site using your Stack Exchange account (that is, entering your email and password will **not** create a new user just for this site). Confirm it and voilà, you're the community's newest member.