# Can't login to Area 51

Tags: bug, status-completed, area-51, login, openid

When logging in into Area 51 (with my Stack Exchange credentials), I'm greeted with the following cryptic error message:

[image]

I've tried clearing the cache and using another browser, but nothing helps. Where I'm living, it's not [July 1st, 2018](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/307647/support-for-openid-ends-on-july-1-2018) yet. Strangely enough, when I navigate to [Area 51's discussion zone](https://area51.meta.stackexchange.com), I *am* logged in.

Comment: Not that strangely enough... :) A51 Discuss is running our normal Q&A software, so it is able to use your session from here. Area 51 itself does not.

Comment: More to your point, I see the exception on our end and will follow up with someone to get it fixed up.

Comment: @AdamLear: While you're getting someone to poke around in that code, could you also have them take a look at [this issue](https://area51.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/13597/area-51-openid-login-is-broken-with-https)?

Comment: @IlmariKaronen Agh, that’s been on my/Nick’s list for a while now. Need to do a redirect to HTTPS and that should fix it. Just haven’t had the time. :/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should be fixed in the latest build.

The bug was... complicated:

- For security reasons users who are in the [Teams Beta](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/364145/coming-soon-stack-overflow-for-teams) can no longer add [logins we're planning to deprecate](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/307647/support-for-openid-ends-on-july-1-2018).
- Because of historical reasons, Area 51 login includes an "add a credential"-step that isn't amenable to determining whether a login is "good enough" for Teams purposes.
- So, for now, Area 51 can no longer add credentials to accounts that are in a Team.
- I introduced a bug that messed up the "does this credential need to be added"-check.
- So anyone who logged in to Area 51 ran a chance (depending on what login they used) that login would "fail" (but actually succeed, because only the credential add failed).