# Would Stack Exchange consider Portier-based logins?

Tags: support, login, user-accounts, openid

[Portier](http://portier.io) is a passwordless login mechanism based on your email address. It uses Google OAuth for Gmail addresses, and magic links sent via regular email for other domains.

It considers itself a spiritual successor to Mozilla Persona (which never took off), and has a decentralized philosophy similar to OpenID 2.0 (which [didn't take off, eventually](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/307647)).

Portier is currently in beta. What would SE be looking for to consider adopting it as an alternative or replacement for password-based authentication? (Note: this is about SE as a consumer, not a provider.)

It might be helpful to consider a breakdown of the [99.9% not using OpenID](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/307647). How many are using Facebook (doesn't fit with Portier), Google (supported by Portier) and email (supported by Porter) to log in? Portier would reduce login options to Facebook / email.