# I cannot login to Stack Exchange websites through my AOL OpenID

Tags: support, login, user-accounts, openid

I cannot login to Stack Exchange's websites through my AOL OpenID. The Stack Exchange site I try to connect to (i.e. Stack Overflow) says :

```
No OpenID endpoint found.
```

I have tried to get a password reminder from Stack Overflow, but once I am logged I am using a *new* account ( => not the account using OpenID to connect).

**How could I log in / recover my account ?**

PS: I have searched solutions, but this post about OpenID does not answer the question : [Support for OpenID ends on August 15, 2018](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/307647/support-for-openid-ends-on-august-15-2018?newreg=746caaaea9684cd0b3921e0e2070ef5d)

Comment: Losing my old account will have an impact on my work (I cannot create bounties anymore, as I don't have enough points), and, even worse, it will be more difficult to get the jobs I want (showing a stackoverflow profile with many points is, to some people who are recruiting, impressive)... so it is an important issue.

Comment: Have you used the contact link at the bottom of any page?

Comment: @Catija that is a great idea, I have just done as you have suggested.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have created a new account then contacted them through the contact link at the bottom of the page. After my request there, they merged the old one to the new one.