# Logged in throughout the network, but not on SO

Tags: support, login, openid

I'm logged in on scifi.SX, and here on meta.SX - but not on Stackoverflow.com . What's more, there doesn't seem to be a box on the login page to enter an OpenID URL.

What gives?

Comment: Different domain, so you have to log in once in there as well. As for OpenID, it's no longer supported by Stack Exchange since July: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/307647/support-for-openid-ended-on-july-25-2018.

Comment: ^ If you're using openID here now to log in, change your authentication method ASAP.

Comment: @doppelgreener: I am :-(

Comment: @einpoklum You can add credentials [at this link](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/login-add), if you haven't already, and [manage your credentials here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/mylogins/current)