# Can't access my ServerFault account

Tags: support, login, yahoo

The "Yahoo" login is no longer an option and, although I can still use most of the sites (including Meta, obviously), the ServerFault no longer recognizes [me](https://serverfault.com/users/160236/mikhail-t).

Trying to use the "Forgot Password" option does not work - I never get the promised instructions e-mail.

Please, advise.

*Update*: I actually do have another login:
[image]

As you can see, I've had it for years, but have usually used Yahoo. However, when I try to login with that e-mail now, I get a rejection. When I choose the "Forgot" option and use the address to recover the access, I get a promise, that an instruction email has been sent -- but none ever arrives...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

OpenID (like Yahoo) [isn't supported any more](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/307647/162102).  You need to add a Google, Facebook, or email-based sign-in to your account while you're still logged in.  You were able to ask this question, so presumably you're logged in on Meta.  Add a credential, and then use that to log in to your linked account elsewhere.

I've been getting randomly logged out of sites for the last day or so, after months of no disruption, so if you're relying only on an OpenID account, get an alternative in place quickly in case you get logged out here.  The [help](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/edit-credentials) still refers to OpenID including Yahoo, but aside from that incorrect text, the instructions for how to add credentials are still good.

Regarding your update: the other login you show (last used in 2014) has what looks like a generic OpenID icon.  Even though the ID appears to be an email address, that's not an SE email-based login.  For comparison, here's what mine look like.  The first one is an email login that I created specifically for SE when they announced that OpenID would be going away.  Note the SE icon, in contrast to the icon on yours.  As you can tell, I don't use it much -- it's my backup in case Google should ever fail me.  SE did not previously allow adding an email login to an account that had some other credential; they changed that when they deprecated OpenID, to allow those of us who only had one of Google or Facebook to still have a backup method of logging in.

[image: annotated screenshot]

Comment: I just had a forced logout as well.  I wonder what's up.

Comment: Thanks, @monica-cellio, I just updated my answer - I do have another login option already, but it is not not working...

Comment: @MikhailT.  see my update.  Your other login looks like some other OpenID credential, not the email-based logins that SE supports.

Comment: @Mikhail If it shows up under Other, that means it is only a verified email address that was used for sending email notifications (either currently or in the past) and is not set up as a credential that can be used for login. It needs to be listed under Stack Exchange to be usable as an email/password login.

Comment: I just added yet another e-mail address -- with password -- and it is now _also_ listed under "Other". But now I can login -- using this new addition, so I'm Ok...