# Why would StackExchange logs show me logging in *from* a stack exchange server?

Tags: bug, login, security

Looking at my login history (at https://openid.stackexchange.com/user) I see I've logged in several times from the IP address "198.252.206.71" but according to a quick whois search, that IP belongs to "Stack Exchange, Inc." I'm imagining it's probably a bug in SE's logging but wondering if it could be a loopback / IP spoofing attack by some bot or...?

---

Irrelevant info to pre-empt off topic questions:

- Because I found my email (again) on https://haveibeenpwned.com/
- Yes, I had a weak password on here (relatively speaking; it was under 15 chars and used my old pre-salting technique)
- No, I do not see any unusual activity on my SE account
- Yes, I changed the password

Comment: Does anyone else see similar activity or is it just me?

Comment: I think its a semi known bug. I've seen it a few times as a mod.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is likely the remnants of an internal API call on our end, which we will be deprecating soon, OR possibly you have found your home is a wormhole in which you exist both there and our NYC office at the same time!

[This post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/307647/support-for-openid-ended-on-july-25-2018) on meta has more info about the sunsetting of OpenID which will likely make the SO IP stop popping up for you like that.

Either way, I wouldn't worry about it. Best case scenario you can pop in for a NYC slice and be home in time for dinner.

Comment: Is that NYC slice for cheesecake or pizza? In either case, now I want to partake in this bug; and I won't have to be home in time for dinner.

Comment: Great question, I meant pizza but the cheesecake is also delicious. Basically YMMV.