# Unify login across all Stack Exchange sites

Tags: feature-request, login, user-accounts

Currently, almost every Stack Exchange site has its own login area, meaning the browsers login auto fill doesn't always work.

For example:

Stack Overflow login: `stackoverflow.com/users/login`
Physics Stack Exchange login: `physics.stackexchange.com/users/login`

If I've saved my login credentials for Stack Overflow, they don't work for Physics Stack Exchange. I have to save them again, and vice-versa.

I propose a solution similar to that of Googles' is implemented,

`accounts.stackexchange.com` shared by all Stack Exchange sites.

**EDIT**

Someone has flagged this as a duplicate of [this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/260153/global-auth-is-dead-long-live-universal-login), but I assure you, it is not. That post is about how sites behave **after** logging into one of the sites, and this post is about unifying the login experience across all the Stack Exchange sites, so browser login auto-fill only needs to remember one set of credentials for one address: `accounts.stackexchange.com`

**EDIT**

Here's a screenshot of my browsers password manager, ridiculous!!

All the credentials are the same.

[image: Chrome password manager]

Comment: I still don't understand how you end-up with credentials for all these sites. Did you also disable thirdparty-cookies or is there another reason universal login didn't work for you, leaving you no other option then to login on all those sites again?

Comment: @rene This is about browser-saved passwords. This isn't an issue once you're logged in, but when you're logged out your password is only saved on the specific sites you initially logged in to.

Comment: I believe that you can [login by using](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/307647/support-for-openid-ended-on-july-25-2018) Stack Exchange, Google or Facebook; if you don't want to use Google or Facebook you can set up one account on Stack Exchange and use that to login to any of the sites. It would be helpful to include your browser version, OS and password manager. I join new sites regularly (using Google, and no password manager) and it's a few clicks to create a new account. If I'm logged into any one site I'm logged in everywhere that I already have an account (except SEDE).

Comment: @SonictheWizardWerehog I know how that works. Still don't understand the usage scenario. It must be something like: "Hey, that is an awesome SE site. Let's login because I've never done that before and my cookies didn't persist. Dang, where did I had that credential I used for the other SE site I was on". If the number of logins stored is the problem then this can be mitigated by the user, if they carefully plan on which site they login and then proceed from there. I really doubt if a revisit to unify login *again* is where the SE tdev team needs to spend time on.

Comment: @Rob Re: "if you don't want to use Google or Facebook you can set up one account on Stack Exchange and use that to log in to any of the sites". I have a Stack Exchange account and yet it doesn't show the user id and password I use to log in to Physics SE, when I try to log in to (say) Stack Overflow. Let me emphasize the OP's point: the issue is **not** about *not* getting logged in to Stack Overflow when I log in to Physics SE, **but** rather about the absence of auto-fill (with the Physics SE log in credentials) when I try to log in to Stack Overflow. This isn't a browser dependent issue.

Comment: @Blue is the real problem that the login form does't have the autocomplete attribute set on the input tags?

Comment: @rene Erm, I'm not quite sure what that means (don't really know much about web development). Anyway, I believe the problem is that we don't have a universal all-SE log in i.e. whether a person wishes to log in to Physics SE (`https://physics.stackexchange.com/users/login`) or they wish to log in to Stack Overflow (`https://stackoverflow.com/users/login`), they should be *redirected* to log in through a unified page — something like `https://stackexchange.com/users/login`. That way we don't have to save our log in credentials for each SE site separately.

Comment: @Blue no, it is not enabled. I checked before I posted the comment.

Comment: One of the points of moving away from Global auth (and from StackAuth.com) to Universal login was to get rid of those redirects to different domains and reloads. I leave it to Adam Lear to fill in the exact details what the problems / challenges were but I welcomed the move to universal login. Undoing some of that with the risk of re-instating previous redirect/reload requirements seems counter intuitive.

Comment: @Blue it would solve that you have to re-enter your credentials on each site. It won't  solve that the passwordmanager still stores the credentials for each site. But again, with some self-discipline by always login in into stackexchange.com/users/login  that would be solved.

Comment: Maybe one day! There are a lot of technical hurdles to something like this in how we route things on the network that would at the moment add a lot of complication. However, on .NET Core we could for example handle the accounts domain routing in middleware and this is much more doable and comparatively way, *way* simpler. It's on my list as something we'd like to do for other reasons (e.g. de-duping login screen duplication). We plan to look at authentication after the .NET Core port this year, but have no concrete details past that, just lots of thoughts.

Comment: @NickCraver Awesome, when you get around to doing it, could you also, as part of the change, allow us to have one profile across all SE sites which we can modify in a single place, instead of having the current "copy to all sites" debacle. Thanks.

Comment: @daka Nope :) Because the two aren't at all related. However, that's another project which is very much deep into design phase that will come here to meta as we actually have time to work on it after current items. I think you'll like the new approach - I've been pinged about the architecture to support it along the way and think it'll simplify tremendously for us on the backend and users on the frontend.

Comment: @NickCraver I know that you don't have a planned release date for these features as of yet, but giving a rough estimate, when can we expect these features? (year)

Comment: @daka not sure - auth refactor we hope to *start* this year after .NET Core (that has follow-up projects, though...and we're learning every day). There are so many pieces to that I couldn't estimate a reasonable absolute end date. I have things thrown at the team that have to take high priority, so all my scheduling is relative or unit-based...when we start or get interrupted shifts somewhat frequently specifically for Architecture.

Comment: @NickCraver should we tag this status-review, or is that intended only for shorter-term stuff?

Comment: @MonicaCellio alternatively [tag:status-deferred]?

Comment: @MEE or in its actual name, [tag:status-graveyard]. ;)

Comment: @MEEthesetupwizard having raised the question of a status tag, I leave the specific choice to the SE employee (Nick).

Comment: Hi @NickCraver, any update on this?

Comment: @daka It's not on the roadmap yet, but I hope to be in canary or wrapping up .NET Core this month. After that we'll be consolidating StackAuth and StackSnippets (on our end - users won't see a difference) as well as getting everything Linux-compatible. Those site consolidations will give us a lot of knowledge on what to expect and see what we can do for authentication. There's been a wrench here for everyone with the SameSite cookie shenanigans from Chrome as well - we had to delay anything until we saw how that plays out...since it had the potential to break current universal login.

Comment: @NickCraver Thanks for the quick response, I just wanted to make a quick suggestion, currently, each site allows login and I'm assuming can produce an authentication cookie that can be used by all other sites, instead, only one site (`accounts.stackexchange.com`) should allow login and produce this cookie. Anyway, see you in a year :)

Comment: @daka That piece is the case already today for `stackexchange.com`, but keep in mind that cookie won't work on any sibling domain just due to how cookies work in general (they're never sent to _another_ site). For example, do you login on `stackoverflow.com`? Or `accounts.stackoverflow.com`? Or `accounts.stackexchange.com`? (which would _rely_ on third party cookies). We can't _rely_ on third-party cookies, some people block them...those need to at least work on the current domain. There's also a user issue where we create on the current site...it's not a trivial move, but I am thinking on it!

Comment: @NickCraver Any update on this?

Comment: @NickCraver What about now?

Comment: @NickCraver Soooo

Comment: Guys, it'd really be appreciated if y'all did not have us keep typing our username and password to login to each and every StackExchange website when we've already logged into one. What exactly is the objective of forcing multiple logins?

Comment: Yeah. It's so tiresome that we have to re-enter name and password every time we go into some sub-forum. I think a lot of forums like Server Fault, Meta, Software Eng, etc would see a lot more traffic if access to them were eased.