# Add a login for all my Stack Exchange accounts

Tags: support, login, user-accounts, openid, stack-exchange-openid

THIS IS NOT A DUPLICATE. The other question was about merging two accounts, my problem is to add a login for *all* the StackExchange sites I visit.

I was logging in with OpenID, but now that it's gone, I added an email/password to my Stack Overflow account (at https://stackoverflow.com/users/login-add ) and it seems to work, I can now log in at Stack Overflow and have my old account (https://stackoverflow.com/users/15625/bortzmeyer), with my questions and so on.

But it doesn't work for other Stack Exchange sites. At Server Fault, I now have a new account (https://serverfault.com/users/521787/st%C3%A9phane-bortzmeyer) with all history for the older account (https://serverfault.com/users/2253/bortzmeyer) lost. How can I reconnect to the old account (and the other Stack Exchange accounts), now that OpenID is gone?

Comment: The duplicate is about *link / merge / combine / associate* and of those applies to your case.

Answer (score 1):

> How can I reconnect to the old account (and the other Stack Exchange accounts), now that OpenID is gone?

Use the [contact form](https://serverfault.com/contact) and request for a [merge](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/18232) of those two accounts. You'll need to select the **I need to merge user profiles** option under "**What can we help you with?**" and explain your situation in detail. The message will be directly sent to the Stack Exchange team and you should get a response soon. If and when the merge is successful you should be able to log in to all your accounts with your new email and password.

**Related**: [Support for OpenID ended on July 25, 2018](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/307649)

Comment: Does it have to be done for *all* the StackExchange sitesI use? There are many.

Comment: @StéphaneBortzmeyer No, just do it for any one and explain the situation to them. They'll take care of the rest.