# Universal login without OpenID

Tags: support, openid

I just discovered I can't access to SE sites with my network account any more.
To clarify, in the past, I did not need to create a distinct account for each SE site and, when I was logged to site A, I did not need to login again to access site B.

Searching meta.stackexchange, the only relevant post seems: *[Support for OpenID ended on July 25, 2018](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/307647/support-for-openid-ended-on-july-25-2018)*, which is a detailed post, but it is very cryptic about what needs to be done on the users' side:

> Obviously, if your account relies on OpenID, then make life easy and go now and add your Google or Facebook credentials or set up email/password authentication.

I don't have a Facebook account (luckily) and I am trying to escape Google. Email/password authentication is just fine for me.

However, I don't get how the new email/password system works. Specifically:

1. If I sign-up with same email/password to new Stack Exchange sites, will the accounts be associated to a single network profile?
2. What about existing accounts, without the OpenID? Specifically, how can I log-in avoiding to lose my existing profile data for that site?
3. Is the email I provide strictly tied to my network profile or can I change the email associated to my user ID?