# Remove [openid] as a default tag on per-site metas

Tags: feature-request, status-review, tags, per-site-meta, default-tags

OpenID support has been [mostly removed for a while now](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/307647/support-for-openid-ended-on-july-25-2018), and is [set to be completely removed at the end of October this year](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/381456/openid-endpoints-and-url-will-be-removed-on-november-1-2022).

However, the tag [openid](/questions/tagged/openid) is still one of the [default tags](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/62655/add-a-selection-of-default-tags-to-all-metas) that get added to a per-site meta whenever a new site is created, and always exist on all per-site metas even if there are no questions using the tag. I took a look at the [current, up-to-date list of default tags](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/233922/377214) and [openid](/questions/tagged/openid) is still one of them.

For questions about the current login system, the [login](/questions/tagged/login) tag is also in the list of default tags so it can be used for those, and as was done with the [favorites](/questions/tagged/favorites) tag, this tag can be synonymized to that on currently existing per-site metas on which the tag is being used on current questions. Alternatively, it can be simply removed as a default tag, as was done with the [interesting-tags](/questions/tagged/interesting-tags) tag.

Can [openid](/questions/tagged/openid) please be removed as a default tag on per-site metas?