# Is OpenID deprecated on the Stack Exchange Network?

Tags: support, openid, myopenid

I'm clearing the clutter from my list of login credentials, and I'd like to know if it's alright to delete my personal OpenID from this list?

Comment: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/openid

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Support for OpenID ended on July 25, 2018](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/307647/341145) or else [OpenID endpoints and URL will be removed on November 1, 2022](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/381456/341145)