# Improve/remove OpenID information in the Data Explorer

Tags: feature-request, profile-page, data-explorer, openid

I just looked at my profile in the Stack Exchange Data Explorer:

[image]

First of all, [Support for OpenID ended on July 25, 2018](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/307647/support-for-openid-ended-on-july-25-2018) (well, somewhat later actually) so in my case it can be removed. For the platforms that do still support OpenID, truncating the URL like this isn't optimal, and the vertical alignment can use some further alignment as well (just like the website).