# Joining the TeX Stack Exchange site gives an OpenID error

Tags: bug, 500-server-error, sign-up

I note that [OpenID](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OpenID) support was [discontinued in 2018](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/307647/support-for-openid-ended-on-july-25-2018) (but some loose ends are still being tidied?).

On joining [TeX - LaTeX](https://tex.stackexchange.com/) by clicking through from my network profile on stackexchange.com, upon clicking the confirm in the new-account dialogue, I was referred to this page: https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/openidconfirm

[image: Error page saying oops.]

As it turns out, the account was created just fine, and the association bonus credited too.

I've joined new sites at a rate of perhaps one per [6-8](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19478/the-many-memes-of-meta/19514#19514) weeks for the last few years without any error or anomaly.

**Expected behaviour:**

To be referred to either the home page or to the newly created profile, not an error page.